# When I use .split and .length on a string to find how many times a character occurs in a string, why is the output number always off by one?

Tags: javascript, string, split, higher-order-functions

For instance, WITHOUT using a for loop, I want to count the number of occurrences a character appears in a given string. For instance,

```
function countCharacter(str, char) {
  return (str.split(char).length - 1)
}
```

Unless I put the negative 1 in the code, the number of times 'l' appears in the word 'hello' will output 3. Why is this?

Comment: Are you asking why `"hello".split("l")` returns an array of length 3? Have you examined the result of `"hello".split("l")`? What do you expect that to return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because for example hello split by 2 characters l will become an array of 3 string. “He”, “”, “o” so you need to minus 1.

Comment: Of course, that makes so much sense! Thanks man, stay groovy!

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a string `"aaaBaBaaa"`. If you split it by `"B"`, you are left with the following array: `["aaa", "a", "aaa"]`.

Total number of "B"s is like a number of cuts, but you don't count the number of cuts, but the number of parts. So that is if you count a character this way, the number is of by one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a metaphor that might help: if I ask you to slice a carrot into 3 parts, how many slices do you need to make?

Now let's look at what your code is doing.

The `String.prototype.split()` method splits a string into an array of substrings, and you're using the `char` variable to determine where to make each split.

Let's say you're using it on the string "omit all periods";

`'omit.all.periods'.split('.');`

In this case, I'm splitting my string into array, and it's split along the period character `'.'`, of which there are two.

That gives me an array that looks like this: `["omit", "all", "periods"]`

Even though the length of the array is 3, the actual number of characters I'm splitting against is 2.

I think your misunderstanding is that you aren't taking into account the first substring before the split character - in this case, the word "omit - hence the need to subtract 1 from your calculation.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Your carrot metaphor is spot on. Thank you so much Faisal!

Answer (score 0):

Write it using RegExp:

```
function countCharacter(str, char) {
  return str.match(new RegExp(char, "g")).length;
}
```